# understanding node.js callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using urllib to make a request to a webpage and I'm trying to return it's headers like so:

```
var getHeaders = function(webpage){
    var info = urllib.request(webpage, {}, function(err, data, res){
        // console.log(res.headers); works fine and shows them
        return res.headers; // I thought it should make the info variable have the headers information
    }); 
    return info; 
}
```

Now when I try to get the headers like maybe `set-cookie` of a webpage I intended it to return the that from the website but it doesn't, so is there a way to return the headers or is it just not possible to do that?

Comment: It's just not possible to do that.

Comment: It is Async, so you need to make your workflow Async as well...

Comment: Anything is possible, just add a while loop to block the server until the async call has completed.

Comment: @adeneo you've got a black heart, you do.

Comment: @Pointy - Sometimes, I didn't post it as an answer, or say it was a great idea, but I've seen code where people have actually used while loops because they didn't understand how to work with async methods.

Comment: I was just kidding :)

Comment: @adeneo: In Node.js, that wouldn't even help

Comment: @adeneo I don't think a while loop to deal with async code would ever work.  The async call that could break the conditional would never get executed I believe.  `setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('async executed')
}, 1);
while (1) {};`

Comment: @pllee - it would work just fine for things like ajax, but in node I guess it would just block the entire thread for the most part, and then it wouldn't work.

Comment: @adeneo well you can run that snippet in chrome and it will block the thread forever.  I've never done that before with an ajax request I really don't know what will happen.  Tell those people to use a synchronous `asynchronous javascript and xml` request and get rid of the loops ;)

Answer (score 5):

In Node pretty much everything is done asynchronously, so you'll just need your function to be asynchronous.

```
var getHeaders = function (webpage, done) {
    urllib.request(webpage, {}, function(err, data, res){
        done(err, res.headers);
    });  
}
```

The traditional pattern is to use callbacks that return an error as the first argument (or a falsy value in case everything went well), and whatever you need to return afterwards.

Consuming the method is then very similar to what you had to do with the `urllib` thing.

```
getHeaders(webpage, function (err, headers) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; // or, you know, deal with it.
    }
    console.log(headers);
});
```

Comment: Oh, I see but would that be possible to do in one function? I'm just curious on how things I should do things in node since I'm new to it

Comment: Synchronous code which depends on asynchronous code isn't doable. You can only return values in functions which don't depend on asynchronous code. In an async world, use callbacks.

Comment: Okay, so I added a callback and tried something like, `var something = getHeaders(webpage, function(err, data, res) { return res.headers; });` Which returned undefined as I thought is their any way I can assign the res.headers to a returnable value?